# How do I apply shrink wrap to WordPress's NextGen gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, image, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme for my website and a [NextGen gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) plugin for the gallery page (thumbnails, enlarged when clicked) and I want to protect my images from being stolen.

I have disabled mouse functions but I also want to do shrink wrap

I have this code for shrink wrapping:

```
<table style="display: inline;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr height="600">
<td style="background-image: url(1.jpg);" width="800"><img src="2.gif" width="800" height="600" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is, where do I place this code? (I need this both for the thumbnails and on the enlarged images)

If you need more info (ftp screenshots, the url of my site or anything else) let me know and I will edit

Comment: Is your question about "protecting images from being stolen" or how to apply shrink wrap to NextGen gallery?

Comment: This is often asked. The answer is that any image a user may see in his browser can be saved by the user. Punto.

Comment: Fabrício Matté- exactly! my question is about how to apply shrink wrap to NextGen gallery

Comment: How do I apply shrink wrap to NextGen gallery?

Answer (score 6):

You can't stop users from "stealing" your images.  If the images are on the website, they'll be downloaded to the user's computer *somewhere* (said somewhere can be found with little effort in Chrome's dev tools) and a dedicated thief will be able to steal them.  Instead, lower the resolution of the pictures you'll serve up so they'll have less value (plus, they'll load faster!) and add a watermark.

Disabling mouse functions won't work, as the user can simply disable JavaScript (an incredibly easy task).

Heck, the user could just fire up something like [Awesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en) and crop out everything but the image.

The moral of the story is that anything that's on the frontend of your website is fair game.  There are ways to protect yourself, but nothing perfect.

Comment: the heck you mean I cant? I can edit the plugin source, I only need to add this little code but I don't know where to place it in the plugin source

Comment: You can't stop users from stealing your images.

Comment: @JohnSmith Your little HTML snippet there won't change the fact that images are being downloaded to your computer automatically.

Comment: I know a dedicated thief can steal them but the audience my website is targeting is totally different, the only know to right click and save as or drag the picture to the URL bar so this code will cover enough for me and also I have a copyright statement on my website I just want to be sure that I am doing everything I can to prevent my pictures from being stolen (its not a content site its a business site I made for my friend, his competitors are old people they are too dumb to know how to disable javascript or use chrome's dev tools)

Comment: Rule #1 of development: Never underestimate your users.